# A safe way to use older versions of an R package under linux

Tags: r, deprecated, r-package, multiple-versions

Sometimes I need to run old codes in R which have been written some time ago using versions of packages different from what I use now with my current R version.
When I do not need to update and correct the script with the newer functions of the current packages, but only to ckeck the results of those scripts, what is the safer way to go? Till know I have found two possibilities.

1. Installing multiple R versions with their associated 'old' packages and shifting from one version to another as needed if this is possible maybe from rstudio.
2. Having only one R version (assuming this would be a relatively recent one) and using old packages when needed, in case this doesn't get into dependencies problems for using old packages with a newer version of R.

The first option was a total disaster for me as I tried to install other versions of R in different ways, also had to "tune" my debian distribution (bullseye) to accept the latest R version, it became unstable and finally I had to format my PC.
Related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017879/use-function-from-a-package-but-different-versions-simultaneously) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594227/compile-an-older-r-version-and-switch-between-versions-in-ubuntu-and-rstudio), but before giving the suggested solutions a try, I wanted to know if other options exist.
So I would appreciate any insights about the easier and safer way of running old scripts with their old packages/functions.

Comment: Hi Andres. Opinion-based questions are off topic here. I would suggest you [edit] your question so that it doesn't sound like you are soliciting opinions.

Comment: See e.g. `renv` package and https://rocker-project.org/

Comment: See Posit's Package Manager, which provides per-date repos: https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/

Comment: @r2evans ‘renv’ helps to prospectively future-proof R code. It doesn’t help with retrospectively running an old project that didn’t have ‘renv’ set up back then.

Comment: Option (1) is definitely possible without rendering your system unstable. And for some code this might be the only option, since there have been numerous small compatibility-breaking changes to R over the years (most of these won’t affect most code, however).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I thought the packagemanager allows you to set a "date", where it will offer you versions of the package that were current on that date; as such, doesn't it allow you to retroactively setup an `renv` environment?

Comment: Andres, a clear path would be Dirk's suggestion: setup a lib-path (for whatever version of R you want) that has the version of packages at that time. That is effectively what `renv` does. I think starting with `renv` now has the complication that it will by default install packages that are current today, which is not the starting point you want; for that, I think Posit's Package Manager will allow you to install packages that were current on a specific date, which allows you to pick and choose, though there are limits to how far back they go, I think.

Comment: Though I think Posit's PM also allows you to install specific versions (not necessarily based on date), which might give you the advantage of having the "key" packages be a certain version, and other packages might be newer (or not) with less risk/consequence to you. That's a hard one to predict, though, since package interactions can be finicky.

Comment: @r2evans Ah, that’s a new function in a recent version, right? Yes, that might work. (EDIT: hang on, I meant to reply to Ben, not you; but I think ‘renv’ also has this now.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. @r2evans, could I use Posit package manager with 'normal' rstudio (eg. 2023.09.1 Build 494) which is not Pro? I found this, which apparently only applies to rstudio pro: https://docs.posit.co/ide/server-pro/r/using_multiple_versions_of_r.html

Comment: Yes. Go to the link I provided above, look for the ["Setup"](https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/repos/cran/setup) button and click it. It walks you through setting it up in RStudio. (Just because a commercial offering supports the Package Manager (PM) doesn't mean that PM requires a commercial client.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works quite well by taking advantage of the ability of R to use different library paths. You can set these via `.libPaths()` easily.

As a concrete example, I happen to like using `roxygen2` version 6.0.1. So I keep it in a directory my 'normal' R installation does not know about. In a helper script (as I also like to use this from the command-line) I then do

```
if (dir.exists("~/.R/cache/roxygen2")) {
    cat("** Using cached version 6.0.1 of roxygen2.\n")
    .libPaths("~/.R/cache")
}

## load roxygen
library(roxygen2)
```

and on a machine with that directory present, it will be prefixed to the library path and that older roxygen version is used in this session.

You can easily generalize this. We have done so for continuous integration and other use cases.

Another example is *e.g.* provided by my use of `r-devel` as it has its own library path (so that I can have package compiled by `r-devel` followed by the system one (so that I do not have to rebuild all packages):

```
$ RD -q -e '.libPaths()'
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R-devel/lib/R/library" 
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"       
> 
$
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Dirk-Eddelbuettel for your reply. I like this suggestion and am giving it a try. I succesfully changed the values at .libPaths() so that when I install an old package, eg. install.packages("url_to_old_package", repos = NULL, type = source), the new package goes to my new custom directory, such as "/home/andres/R/my_new_folder". But I wonder if everything stays neat when the package depends on others that need to be install too. Will R o rstudio know which version of those packages to choose to maintain compatibility among all the old packages?

Comment: RStudio runs the same R interpreter as you so you need to find a way to adjust, and re-adjust back, the `.libPaths()`. Maybe within a calling function that acts as a wrapper.  That is up to you.  Dependencies get resolved the usual way: by looking at the whole `.libPaths()` so they have to be "somewhere", maybe in your new directory. I mostly illustrated a basic way in which R can already do this which other packages (such as `renv`) also take advantage of (as I understand it).

Comment: Thank you Dirk. For now your suggestion of installing old packages in a different directory, 'playing' with .libPaths() or even specifying the destination folder in the install.packages() is working pretty well.